# Angular 4 bs datepicker color change

Tags: angular, datepicker

How can I change the color of the bs datepicker theme in the CSS file.

I have tried changing it in the `.css` file, its not reflecting `.PFB`, the code:

```
.theme-green .bs-datepicker-head {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

I have added background color to orange in the `.theme-green .bs-datepicker-head`, but it's not working.

In https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker I could see that in dropdown, color themes have been defined, on select of it color of the date picker are getting changed accordingly.

I need bs datepicker theme set up in the CSS file. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried background-color: orange !important;

Comment: no it's not working

Answer (score 1):

To change the ngx-bootstrap datepicker to custom color of your choice, add the following lines in styles.scss file:

```
.bs-datepicker-head,
.bs-datepicker-head, .bs-datepicker button:active,
.bs-datepicker-body table td span.selected,
.bs-datepicker-body table td.selected span,
.bs-datepicker-body table td span[class*="select-"]:after,
.bs-datepicker-body table td[class*="select-"] span:after,
.bs-datepicker-body table td.active-week span:hover 
{
  background-color: #2dfbcd !important; 
}

.bs-datepicker-body table td.week span 
{
  color: #2dfbcd !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try:

`:host /deep/ .theme-green .bs-datepicker-head {
    background-color: orange;
}`

Can read about [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

Comment: This host selector is working for bootstrap tabs theme change,but not working for bs datepicker theme change.

Comment: If you make a plunkr demo I could debug further.

Comment: Or you can try apply the `theme-orange` with the `bsConfig` object in the `.ts` code as suggested in the `Themes` section of the `ngx-bootstrap` docs